# NServiceBus Installer fails to create tables

Tags: nservicebus

I have installed a 5 services using the following, similar  command:

```
/install /serviceName:"ADS-CI-DQC.UKHO.SIP.OrderFulfilment.ServiceBus.Enp.Holdings" /displayName:"ADS-CI-DQC.UKHO.SIP.OrderFulfilment.ServiceBus.Enp.Holdings" /description:"Orderfulfilment Holdings service" /endpointConfigurationType:"UKHO.SIP.OrderFulfilment.ServiceBus.Enp.Holdings.Program, UKHO.SIP.OrderFulfilment.ServiceBus.Enp.Holdings" /username:"username" /password:"password"
```

four services and a saga. None of the services will start but the saga service is up and running. The Saga did not require the endpointconfigurationtype parameter but none of the other services would install without it. On each of them there is an error message:

```
Failed to execute installers: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A
n object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify
each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliase
s defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify
 each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Alias
es defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolea
n breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObj
ect stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand
 cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,
TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName,
Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSou
rce`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean
asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.SqlServerQueueCreator.CreateQueueIfNecess
ary(Address address, String account) in c:\BuildAgent\work\888dd942b44bad5a\src\
NServiceBus.SqlServer\SqlServerQueueCreator.cs:line 39
   at NServiceBus.Satellites.SatellitesQueuesCreator.Install(String identity, Co
nfigure config) in c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Sate
llites\SatellitesQueuesCreator.cs:line 30
   at NServiceBus.Features.InstallationSupport.Starter.Run(Configure config) in
c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Installation\Installati
onSupport.cs:line 75
   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in c:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\
src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:line 125
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1 moreConfiguration)
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Install(String username)
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Installers.WindowsInstaller.RunInstall()
ClientConnectionId:0d592dd2-ce34-4b31-9b94-e53f776e1264
Error Number:1038,State:4,Class:15
```

I have found suggestions that my username may be at fault because it has .co.uk in it but the same user is used for the Saga and that has created tables. I am using outbox = true and I have turned off the MSDTC service. I am using version 6.0 of the NServiceBus Host.exe which, I think, includes a fix for the outbox tables. that was related to losing messages once installed so I don't think is related.

I am able to manually create the tables by copying existing structure but I would like to fix this.

Comment: Profiled the db and this is the error I get:  An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. Does anyone know how I control this through config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and in the end it was quite simple. I was missing `DefaultTransportSchema="dbo" DefaultPersistenceSchema="dbo"` from the `<NServiceBusConfig>` tag in four of the five config files. Adding them allows the install to work